# Julia MetaCollection: implement collection of collections

Tags: indexing, collections, iteration, julia

In Julia, I want to implement a struct that holds a collection of (heterogeneous) collections.
The semantics of iteration and indexing should be intuitive, i.e. run over the first collection, then continue with the next collection, until done.
I'm looking for the best ways to implement the associated basic functions such as length, access by index and iteration.
Ideally I'd like to re-use pre-existing utility functions (such as Iterators.flatten) rather than manually doing bounds checking and indexing.

This is what I have so far: the length function was straightforward, but I'm stuck on indexing and iteration

```
struct MetaCollection
    collections::Vector
end

Base.length(meta_collection::MetaCollection) = sum(length.(meta_collection.collections))

function Base.iterate(meta_collection::MetaCollection, state::Int64=1)
    # Base.iterator should not return another iterator, but something along these lines
    return ... Iterators.flatten(meta_collection.collections...)
end

Base.getindex(meta_collection::MetaCollection, i::Int64) = ...
```

A usage example could be something like

```
mc = MetaCollection([["a","b","c"],[1,2,3]])

@test length(mc) == 6
@test mc[5] == 2
for x in mc println(x) end
```

Comment: Maybe it's useful to take a look at https://github.com/JuliaDiffEq/RecursiveArrayTools.jl which implements an array of arrays type.

Comment: BTW, I assume that for arbitrary collections you're facing a highly non-trivial problem. For some collections, `length` isn't even defined. See the iteration interface: https://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/manual/interfaces/#man-interface-iteration-1. In this spirit, `getindex` really isn't something _collection like_ but _array like_. Think of a `Set` for example. It clearly is a collection but not indexable.

Comment: I think what I want is something in between: I want the "collections" to be more general than arrays (including iterable custom types etc.), but I assume that the sub-collections all implement the methods that I want to implement for the meta-collection (such as length, getindex, etc).

Comment: `RecursiveArrayTools.jl` was useful for iteration, thanks

Comment: A minor improvement would be to store the `boundaries` as a field of the struct. You can write a separate constructor for the struct that automatically computes computes them. Then the indexing would be faster (if you do it multiple times).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question with what I've come up with and learned from the comments

```
struct MetaCollection
    collections::Vector
end

Base.length(meta_collection::MetaCollection) = sum(length.(meta_collection.collections))

function Base.getindex(meta_collection::MetaCollection, i::Int64)
    boundaries = cumsum(vcat([0], length.(meta_collection.collections)))
    i_c = searchsortedfirst(boundaries, i) - 1
    return meta_collection.collections[i_c][i-boundaries[i_c]]
end

# function Base.iterate(meta_collection::MetaCollection, state::Int64=1)
#     return state <= length(meta_collection) ? (meta_collection[state], state+1) : nothing
# end

# adapted from RecursiveArrayTools.jl
Base.iterate(meta_collection::MetaCollection) = iterate(Iterators.flatten(meta_collection.collections))
Base.iterate(meta_collection::MetaCollection, state) = iterate(Iterators.flatten(meta_collection.collections), state)
```